# How do I write my own authentication protocol and add that to OpenWrt?

Tags: authentication, network, wifi, protocols

I would like to add a ticket based authentication mechanism to my network. Can you give me brief idea where do I start, which language should i write the protocol in and how do i get those in my custom OpenWrt firmware. Thank you!

(Edit)
In a traditional mesh network seamless connection is hard to achieve since as the client moves from one MAP(mesh access point) to another so it needs to re-authentication once again which will cause trouble in applications like video call and voice calls.
I read a dozen of research papers and found out that ticket based authentication is one of the best solution for fast authentication  thereby providing a seamless connection.
[link to the paper] : https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0155064
This is something i am trying to implement.

Was looking for some guidance as to how can i start this.

Comment: It's highly recommended *NOT* to write your own custom authentication protocols. Just use the existing tools. The popular ones should already be tested by lots of professionals, way better than you can test your own, especially if you're new to it. If you write your own, it'll most likely be full of security issues not vetted by professionals. You can learn to write your own software, but just stick with using standard stuff. It's generally better tested.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider writing a [pluggable authentication module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_module) (PAM) that you can use with OpenWRT.  From the Wikipedia article linked above, you can see:

> A pluggable authentication module (PAM) is a mechanism to integrate multiple low-level authentication schemes into a high-level application programming interface (API). It allows programs that rely on authentication to be written independent of the underlying authentication scheme.

From the links below, tt looks like OpenWRT supports integration with PAMs:

https://openwrt.org/packages/pkgdata/libpam

https://forum.openwrt.org/t/installing-google-authenticator-for-ssh-openconnect-openvpn/31439

Answer (score 0):

> Can you give me brief idea where do I start

Start with understanding sockets and studying other protocols. Some of the resources I can redirect you to are:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18249847/how-to-build-a-protocol-on-top-of-tcp
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i05pSG0d8Rg
- https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0155064
- https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-write-your-own-protocol-that-sits-on-top-of-TCP-IP

> which language should i write the protocol in

Many other protocols are written in C but you may use any language that helps you implement your design through a socket.